# Convert String to Date column

Tags: python

I want to convert String column to Date column, but as a result I receive column with null values.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, from_unixtime, dayofmonth, unix_timestamp, year, to_date, col

dane3.withColumn('date', to_date(unix_timestamp(col('dateRep'),'%d.%m.%Y').cast("timestamp"))).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `%` before `d/m/y` like sql. More info [in the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime)

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '27.08.2020'), 
        (2, '27.08.2019'),
    ],
    ['id', 'txt']
)

df = df.withColumn('formatted', 
                   to_date(unix_timestamp(col('txt'), 'dd.MM.yyyy').cast("timestamp")))
df.show()

+---+----------+----------+
| id|       txt| formatted|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|27.08.2020|2019-12-29|
|  2|27.08.2019|2018-12-30|
+---+----------+----------+
```